# Implementing a queue with the Python-Rom Redis ORM

Tags: python, redis

I am working with flask and redis. I use the [rom redis orm](http://pythonhosted.org/rom/) to manage some mildly complex data structures. I want to use a queue of model objects, with the ability to push or pop objects off either end.

I have the following rom model:

```
class A(rom.Model):
    url = rom.String(required=True, unique=True)()
    t = rom.String()
    delete_at = rom.Float(index=True)
    created_at = rom.Float(default=time.time, index=True)
```

I see that at the command line when I run `obj._columns` (with `obj` being a single instance of class `A`), that there is an `id` field. My first thought on how to approach this is to order by `id`:

```
queue = A.get_by(id).
```

This would allow easy addition to the back of the queue, by setting:

```
obj.id = len(queue)+1
```

But I'm not sure how to insert into the 0 element of the list which would require renumbering of the ids of the entire list.

Am I on the right track here? What is the best way to implement a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't implement a queue with rom. If I needed a queue, and I needed to put rom entities in that queue, I would use the raw Redis connection to put entity ids in a Redis list - which offers push and pop from both ends, range scanning, etc.

You can get the raw Redis connection in your example via: `A._connection`.